# Orchard CMS reseting the Culture

Tags: orchardcms, currentculture

I recently watched the very useful [orchard harvest video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sBU3qjb0-w) on localization and internationalization, by Piotr Szmyd

I want to set the culture using this method, checking for a cookie

```
public class CultureSelector : ICultureSelector
    {
        public const int SelectorPriority = 5;
        public const string CookieName = "Riders-Location-Cookie";
        public const string CookieValueName = "location-code";

        public CultureSelectorResult GetCulture(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            if (context == null || context.Request == null || context.Request.Cookies == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // check for a cookie 
            var cookie = context.Request.Cookies[CookieName];

            if (cookie != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Values[CookieValueName]))
            {
                return new CultureSelectorResult { Priority = SelectorPriority, CultureName = cookie.Values[CookieValueName] };
            }

            return null;

        }
    }
```

That works, However, I do want to user to be able to reset their own culture on the site. How do I reset the culture for the entire site when the user chooses to.

Lets say for instance if I have a select list that is output as part of a custom module.

I've looked at the ChangeCulture code form the [Orchard CulturePicker Module](http://orchardculturepicker.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/bc506c0d1729#Controllers/UserCultureController.cs) but this dosen't seem to change to culture for the entier site as setting it with an implementation of ICultureSelector would.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset the culture"? Setting it to a default site culture?

Comment: I just mean Change the culture stie wide.

Comment: CulturePicker module changes the culture site wide. It comes with an implementation of the `ICultureSelector` very similar to what you've posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you'd like a user to be able to *change his current culture and/or be able to return to the default site culture*, right?

In your case it should be as easy as either changing the [cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies.aspx) value or removing it (to set default culture) as a response to some user action.